# How to use AWS CLI and kubectl in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, aws-cli, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in which I want to do the following:

1. Build a Docker image and push it to AWS ECR
2. Restart a specific deployment in my EKS cluster that uses this Docker image

Building and pushing the Docker image works fine, however I'm failing to connect to my EKS cluster.

My idea is to use `aws eks` to update my kubeconfig file, and `kubectl` to restart my deployment, but I don't know how to use the AWS CLI and Kubectl in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

I have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID`, and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` defined in my CI/CD variables. I've got the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy staging

<build stage omitted for brevity>

staging:
  stage: deploy staging
  image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
  only:
    - staging
  script: |
    # install AWS CLI
    apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip \
      && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
      && pip3 install awscli \
      && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
    aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-west-1 --name my-cluster-name
    kubectl rollout restart deployment my-deployment
```

This pipeline fails with the error:

```
error: unknown command "sh" for "kubectl"
Did you mean this?
    set
    cp
```

I've found [this issue and solution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/65110), but changing the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file accordingly prevents me from using `apk` and installing the AWS cli:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy staging

<build stage omitted for brevity>

staging:
  stage: deploy staging
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  only:
    - staging
  script: |
    # install AWS CLI
    apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip \
      && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
      && pip3 install awscli \
      && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
    aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-west-1 --name my-cluster-name
    kubectl rollout restart deployment my-deployment
```

Results in the error:

```
$ # install AWS CLI # collapsed multi-line command
/bin/bash: line 140: apk: command not found
/bin/bash: line 144: aws: command not found
```

So that leads me to the following question: how do I use both the AWS CLI and Kubectl in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? Or is there another easier way that allows me to restart a deployment in my EKS cluster?

Comment: Easier is subjective, but there are more purpose built tools like argocd and fluxcd.

Comment: Since you have an ECR I would suggest to build your own container, take the bitnami kubectl and install AWS cli in it. 
once you are done push the container to your ECR and in the gitlab pipeline reference your ECR image rather than the Docker standard one

Comment: @daniloPatrucco thanks! I already push the container to my ECR. How would you suggest I reference the image? How does it relate to restarting my deployment?

Comment: scrap that, try to use entrypoint: [""] under the image like described in this: 

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/65110

Comment: @DaniloPatrucco Thanks! See the last part of my question: if I do that, I'm unable to install the AWS CLI using `apk add ..`. Any idea how I can solve that?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it myself. For future readers: using the [alpine/k8s](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/k8s) image solves my problem. It has both Kubectl and AWScli installed.